# Can I get the way to change CPLEX to CBC solver?

Tags: c++, cplex, coin-or-cbc

I have MIP program based on CPLEX solver(feasibility pump2.0).

My task is Make this program runs on CBC solver.

So I tried to change the codes with corresponding functions, but program size is too big to modifying every CPLEX code(size of source code is almost 2MB).

Do you know effective way or helpful reference?

Comment: Depends on what's happening in this code and other details. But if this code is based on it's proprietary API (and not a wrapper like CoinOR OSI) and the task is driven by license-like issues (goal = not using CPLEX at all), there is not much besides porting it all: either from scratch or by wrapping the proprietary API (more structured). This will be painful. If it's just about trying a second solver: write LP-files out and populate Cbc with that.

Comment: As sascha says, it depends on what API you use. If you have used the Concert API from C# for example, there is a wrapper around the CoinOR OSI interface called Sonnet, which has a similar API to Concert and that can help make the translation/port to another solver easier. We also have a C++ version of this wrapper, but it is unsupported and not thoroughly tested.

Comment: Thank you for advice! I never thought about that.

Answer (score 0):

Things may be more complicated then you envision at the moment: I doubt that there is an equivalent CBC function for each CPLEX function. Even if a function has the same signature, it may have slightly different semantics. So will have to check those one by one anyway. Some CPLEX functions may not even have an equivalent in CBC and some features used may not be supported by CBC.

A better approach would be (like some comments suggested) to adapt the code so that it uses some abstract and generic interface for which you have an implementation by CBC and CPLEX. Then you can swap out the underlying solver any time.

In case you don't want to move to an abstract interface, you best option probably is to

1. Find every CPLEX function used by the code.
2. Find an equivalent function in CBC. If an exact equivalent does not exist then create your own function with the exact same signature and semantic that is based only on CBC features.
3. Do a search/replace over the code.

The difficult step here is 2. It heavily depends on which CPLEX functions your code uses and how easy it is to map them to CBC functions.

Comment: Thank you. This will be helpful when I set modifying strategy.